# Is there a delivery guarantee when I call CacheEntryEvent.getOldValue() for CacheEntryUpdatedListener in ContinuousQuery

Tags: java, ignite

I have a service that uses ContinuousQuery with continuousQuery.setLocalListener() configuration.

I'm calling *CacheEntryEvent.getOldValue()* inside the *onUpdated(Iterable<CacheEntryEvent<? extends BinaryObject, ? extends BinaryObject>> events)* method of the listener.

My question is, is there a possibility that I will get null even if the old event is presented in the cache?

Because CacheEntryEvent doc says the following:
*The old value will be available
for {@link CacheEntryUpdatedListener}, {@link CacheEntryExpiredListener}
and {@link CacheEntryRemovedListener}
if {@link CacheEntryListenerConfiguration#isOldValueRequired()} is true.
The old value may be available for {@link CacheEntryUpdatedListener},
{@link CacheEntryExpiredListener} and {@link CacheEntryRemovedListener}
if {@link CacheEntryListenerConfiguration#isOldValueRequired()} is false.*

But there is no way to configure CacheEntryListenerConfiguration#isOldValueRequired() for a listener in ContinuousQuery.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is the first time I disagree with the Community Bot :) This is actually a good question. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

Normal `ContinuousQuery` always delivers the old value.

There is another kind of continuous queries that is inherited from the JCache specification, and is configured with all these `CacheEntryListenerConfiguration` classes, and started via `CacheConfiguration#getCacheEntryListenerConfigurations`. Don't worry about those.

A lot of confusion in the current Ignite API (2.x) comes from that it implements JCache natively (and not as an add-on). When you see JCache (`javax.cache`) interfaces in Ignite, be a bit skeptical towards the spec. When you use a mix of JCache and Ignite interfaces, you'll get "a mix" of the behavior. That said, if you use *only* JCache interfaces and not Ignite-specific ones, you'll get the behavior from the JCache spec.